# C# OleDB CSV Import converting characters on its own

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, csv, oledb

I have a CSV document with the headers shown as below:

> Date,Time,TIRCA-501 [°C],PIRCA-501 [MPa],TIRCA-502 [°C],TIRCA-503 [°C],TIR-504 [°C],WTRIA-501 [°C]

(The actual csv file is much more longer than that but I've just cut out the relevant part)

Here's the utility method I am using to parse the csv file:

```
public static bool TryReadFromCsvFile(string csvFilePath, out DataTable fileContent, bool isFirstRowHeader)
{
    fileContent = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        string header = isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";

        string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(csvFilePath);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(csvFilePath);

        string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "] ";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
            String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"{0}\";Extended Properties=\"Text;CharacterSet=65001;ImportMixedTypes=Text;IMEX=1;HDR={1};FMT=Delimited;TypeGuessRows=0\"",pathOnly,header)))
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
        {
            fileContent.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            adapter.Fill(fileContent);
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Logging utility here
        return false;
    }
}
```

The method generally works fine but for the above data, the square bracket '[' is getting replaced a regular bracket '(' in the end result of the parse.

Just to prove I haven't lost my sanity, here's proof (screenshots taken with debugger):

[image]

[image]

I've also checked the hex code of the problematic square bracket in the original file. It's 5B, [which is clearly denoted as left square bracket in UTF-8.](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

Why does OLEDB import cause this? How can I prevent this behavior?

Edit: I realize there exist many other ways of parsing CSV files. Heck, I can even read the content as list of strings and split by commas. I'm just trying to understand why Oledb causes an issue like this so I can decide whether to scrap the utility method all-together or not. I'd like to see an answer with an authoritative source on this.

Comment: Probably because square brackets are used for long field name escaping in OleDb ( `[this is a long field name]` ).  Try using `TextFieldParser` instead of OleDb.

Answer (score 0):

I am a personal fan of `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` for csv parsing. Add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic. I have saved your header as a ANSI encoded csv.

```
string dataCsv;     
using (var csvReader = new TextFieldParser(
    dataCsv, 
    Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), 
    true))
{
    csvReader.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    csvReader.SetDelimiters(",");

    while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] currentRow = csvReader.ReadFields();
            // turn that to a DataRow
        }
        catch (MalformedLineException ex) { }
    }
    // build the DataTable and add all DataRows 
}
```